# How can you save multiple inputs from a user if you are using a for loop?

Tags: python-3.x

```
for i in n:
    sn = str(input("What is the student's name? "))
    sg = eval(input("What is the student's grade? "))
```

If you do something like this then how would you keep the input from the user and store it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an array:

```
names = []
grades = []
for i in n:
    sn = str(input("What is the student's name? "))
    names.append(sn)
    sg = eval(input("What is the student's grade? "))
    grades.append(sg)
```